# Qual é o equivalente em português a uma "noun phrase"?

Tags: gramática, tradução-inglês, sintaxe, termos-em-inglês

O que seria o equivalente em português a uma "noun phrase"? Penso que seria algo parecido com uma oração substantiva ou com uma locução substantiva.

Estudando inglês, eu vejo falar o tempo todo em *noun phrases* e outras *phrases*, mas não consigo encontrar o equivalente delas em português. As gramáticas de português que eu li, não parecem em nenhum momento falar sobre isso, mas todas as gramática de língua inglesa citam isso todo o tempo.

Comment: Olá Rekoowa, bem vindo à comunidade! Talvez eu soubesse responder a isto, se soubesse o que é uma "noun phrase". :) Deves explicar na tua pergunta o que é uma "noun phrase"; usa inglês se precisares. E para ficar uma pergunta perfeita, inclui também um par de "noun phrases". Cereja em cima do bolo? Esclarecer o que nelas as torna "noun phrases", e que faltando ou estando de maneira diferente as tornaria outro tipo de frases.

Comment: Rekoowa, fiz uma edição menor à estrutura da tua pergunta. Podes ver no [histórico de revisões](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/7879/revisions) as alterações. Se gostares, ótimo ainda bem que ajudou. Mas se preferires a tua versão original (não tem problema nenhum : ), basta escolheres o "rollback" no cabeçalho da tua versão 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em gramática, o termo em inglês "*phrase*" é um [falso amigo semântico (ou heterossemântico)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterossem%C3%A2ntico), pois se assemelha à palavra "*frase*" mas tem significado distinto. A palavra inglesa "*sentence*" seria mais próxima em significado da portuguesa "*frase*" ou "*período*", enquanto "*phrase*" seria equivalente a "***sintagma***".

*Phrases* / *sintagmas* são: [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase)

> […] um grupo de uma ou mais palavras que têm a função de um constituinte
>   na sintaxe de uma frase, uma unidade na hierarquia gramática.

Assim como no inglês, dois tipos comuns são "*noun phrase*" e "*verb phrase*" que seriam "***sintagma nominal***" e "*sintagma verbal*", respectivamente.

No entanto, o uso dessas nomenclaturas não é universal e seu uso depende do nível de análise linguística, diferentes teorias de sintaxe e diferentes autores.

As páginas da Wikipedia, por exemplo, parecem divergir um pouco em cada uma de suas edições. A página da Wikipedia para ["Phrase" (en)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase) está ligada a ["Frase" (pt)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frase). Enquanto a ["Noun phrase" (en)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) não tem correspondente em português, mas tem para espanhol ["Sintagma nominal" (es)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintagma_nominal).

Ambos ["Sintagma" (pt)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintagma) e ["Sintagma" (es)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintagma) são ligados ao menos conhecido ["Syntagma" (en)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntagma_(linguistics)), mas o conteúdo do artigo parece sugerir que esse seria um pouco diferente.

O termo mencionado anteriormente ["Sentence" (en)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(linguistics)) é ligado a ["Período" (pt)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per%C3%ADodo_(gram%C3%A1tica)) e ["Oración" (es)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oraci%C3%B3n_(gram%C3%A1tica)).

Ou seja, é confuso. Acredito que a dificuldade de traduzir termos de meta-linguística (com exceção dos fenômenos mais comuns) deriva do fato de não haver um esforço de padronização internacional dos termos entre as diferentes línguas. Talvez isso aconteça porque cada termo é usado na língua para descrever a própria língua, mas sem compromisso em descrever outras línguas. Isso é compreensível, visto que um fenômeno de uma língua pode não ocorrer em outra ou ocorrer de maneira modificada e exigir subclassificações adicionais diferentes.

Por experiência própria, também estranhei a ausência do termo ao estudar Português na escola. Mas ao estudar árvores sintáticas na faculdade (no Brasil), os termos utilizados para se referir a "*noun phrase*" e "*verb phrase*" eram sempre "*sintagma nominal*" e "*sintagma verbal*".

Como bem observado nos comentários, o termo ["grupo nominal"](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/grupo-nominal/20468) também é utilizado em Portugal.

Comment: Bem vindo, yuri. Você poderia elaborar um pouco, ou incluir uma referência, fonte?

Comment: Ui, ficou uma ótima resposta!!

Comment: Uma achega. Também se usa *grupo nominal*; vê por exemplo [este artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/grupo-nominal/20468) e mais [este com mais exemplos](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/identificacao-do-grupo-nominal/31690). A expressão *falso cognato* é curiosa e enganadora: *frase* e *phrase* são mesmo cognatos, porque tem ambos a mesma origem, o latim *prasis*; terem significados diferentes é um acidente de evoluções divergentes.

Comment: Sabes que podes pôr os links diretamente no texto, como eu fiz no comentário acima, em vez de ter os links cá em baixo? Se quiseres fazer e não souberes como se faz, eu posso fazer um para veres como é.

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários. Você está correto, Jacinto. Eu confundi "falso cognato" e "falso amigo", irei corrigir. Não conhecia "grupo nominal", parece ser o equivalente em Portugal, posso incluir também. Quanto aos links, sei como fazer, mas não sabia qual estilo seria melhor usar aqui.

Comment: Yuri, cada um usa o estilo que gosta. Eu acho mais prático para o leitor ter o link logo no texto. Também se usa *sintagma nominal* em Portugal; creio (não tenho a certeza) que *grupo* é terminologia mais recente. Acerca de *falsos cognatos*, a confusão talvez não tenha sido tua: vem no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/cognato) como equivalente a *falsos amigos*, o único dicionário em que encontrei. A [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognato) sabe desse uso, mas diz que é errado, precisamente porque "duas palavras semelhantes de sentidos diversos podem ser cognatos legítimos". >>

Answer (score 2):

Olá, Rekoowa!

Não sei você, mas eu gosto de papel e vou evitar fontes online.

A obra *English Grammar and Composition*, de Warringer & Griffith, 1977, já consideravam uma *phrase* como "a group of words not containing a verb ans its subject" e adiciona que ela é "used as a single part of speech".

Esses autores apresentam sete categorias de *phrases* (*prepositional*, *adjective*, *adverb*, *participial*, *gerund*, *infinitive* e *apositive*), mas, curiosamente, não mencionam *noun phrase*.

Tomando como referência a *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, de Cunha e Cintra, 1985, nota-se a existência apenas de *sintagma nominal* e de *sintagma verbal*, o qual, por sua vez, pode conter nenhum, um ou mais sintagmas nominais.

Em particular, não há o conceito de sintagma em sete categorias, como as em Inglês; há, contudo o conceito de orações, mas isso já foge ao escopo da discussão

Assim, a transposição do Inglês para o Português não é imediata, nem perfeita e nem sem reentrâncias em casos particulares.

Em comum, temos que cada os sete tipos de *phrases* em Inglês correspondem ao sintagma nominal em Português por não conterem os verbos centrais ao sintagma verbal em Português e que são formas nominais e adjetivas em Inglês

Contudo, há uma hierarquização que permite uma analogia mesmo que imperfeita entre esses termos: o termo em Português que se aproxima, de fato, seria **sintagma**, pois (muito *grosso modo*) em Inglês e em Português *phrases* e *sintagmas* compõem *sentences* e *orações*, as quais compõem *speeches* e *frases*/*períodos* em Inglês e em Português respectivamente.

```
 Inglês   | Português           
----------+---------------
 phrase   | sintagma
 sentence | oração
 speech   | frase/período
```

Acima, "frase é um enunciado de sentido completo, a unidade mínima de comunicação", ao passo que "período é a frase organizada em oração ou orações"; por isso, a barra.

Por fim, respondendo à sua pergunta, *sintagma nominal* parece mais adequado.

Comment: A minha edição da *Nova Gramática* (2014) tem *sintagma nominal* no texto "original" e *grupo nominal* no texto "azul" que explica a mesma coisa usando a "atual terminologia no ensino da língua materna" (p. 158).